# How to check message sending to a JMS queue was unsuccessful?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, queue, jms, publish

I have a requirement where I have to log an error message if the JMS messsage has not been sent to the queue.

How can I check whether the message has not been sent?

**Code:**

```
...
...   
QueueSender send = session.createSender(queue);
TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(message);

send.send(tm);
log.debug("Sent text=" + tm.getText());
...
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

use DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT to ensure it will be persisted and delivered, and catch the JMSException which is raised if send() fails?

Comment: Like this? try { ... QueueSender send = session.createSender(queue);  send.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(message);

send.send(tm); log.debug("Sent text=" + tm.getText()); . . .} catch (JMSException e) { //print "message not sent"}

Comment: yeah, something like that.  It's been a while since I used JMS but from what I remember most of the methods raise JMSExceptions if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Catching exception from the send call is enough. No need to set the delivery mode as PERSISTENT as this option makes all messages as persistent even when you want the message to be non-persistent.

```
try
{
  qsender.Send(msg);
}
catch(JMSException je)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1796/6nmonffeb/index.html) says:

> For more flexibility, Message Queue lets you customize the JMS client-acknowledge mode. In client-acknowledge mode, the client explicitly acknowledges message consumption by invoking the `acknowledge()` method of a message object.